# Prevent Full Postback from __doPostBack

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, dopostback

I have a content page that contains the following...

> 1. UpdatePanel1 - containing Error Display Divs
>        contains update triggers for both buttons
> 2. UpdatePanel2 - containing process 1 with an asp:button
> 3. updatePanel3 - containing process 2 with an asp:button
> 4. JavaScript that presents the user with a Popup confirm Jquery Messagebox based on the process they are executing.

UpdatePanel 2 or 3 becomes visible based on the users selection from the menu options.

[image: selecting menu item 2 will display this page shown with an error message]

When I click a button the messagebox pops and the page is processed correctly using __doPostback from the messagebox response and the page does a full postback.

I would rather the page do a partial postback and the content it had and display the Error Display Divs if there was an error. Any assistance would be appreciated.

nothing special about the button

```
<asp:Button ID="ResetSomething" runat="server" Text="ResetSomething" Width="275px" />
```

here is the content page script block

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
<!--
    function pageLoad() {
        setform();

    };

    function setform() {
        var reset1_button = $('input[id*=ResetSomething]');
        var reset2_button = $('input[id*=ResetSomethingElse]');

        reset1_button.click(function() {
            var element = $(this);
            $.prompt('Message1', { show: 'slideDown', buttons: { Ok: true, Cancel: false },
                submit: function(v, m, f) { submit_reset_callback(v, m, element); }
            });
            return (false);
        });

        var submit_reset_callback = function(result, messages, element) {
            if (result) { __doPostBack("ResetSomething");}
            return (false);
        };

        reset2_button.click(function() {
            var element = $(this);
            $.prompt('Message2', { show: 'slideDown', buttons: { Ok: true, Cancel: false },
                submit: function(v, m, f) { submit_update_callback(v, m, element); }
            });
            return (false);
        });

        var submit_update_callback = function(result, messages, element) {
            if (result) { __doPostBack("ResetSomethingElse"); }
            return (false);
        };
    };     
-->
</script>
```

this is the code behind for the OnInit:

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        this.PreLoad += (sender, args) =>
                            {

                                this.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, "arg");

                                if (!IsPostBack) { return; }

                                string __targetaction = this.Request["__EVENTTARGET"];
                                string __args = this.Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];

                                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(__args)) return;

                                if (__targetaction == "ResetSomething")
                                {
                                    ResetSomething();
                                }
                                if (__targetaction == "ResetSomethingElse")
                                {
                                    ResetSomethingElse();
                                }
                                this.upnlNotifications.Update();
                            };
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the function below and replace your `__doPostBack` calls with `doPostBackAsync(controlId, null)`.

```
function doPostBackAsync(eventName, eventArgs) {
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    if (!Array.contains(prm._asyncPostBackControlIDs, eventName)) {
        prm._asyncPostBackControlIDs.push(eventName);
    }

    if (!Array.contains(prm._asyncPostBackControlClientIDs, eventName)) {
        prm._asyncPostBackControlClientIDs.push(eventName);
    }

    __doPostBack(eventName, eventArgs);
}
```

Comment: The controlId should be the id of the button correct? If so then I still get the same results, a full page postback.

Comment: Got it. __doPostBack(eventName.attr('id'), eventArgs); worked like a charm. Passing just eventName threw a javascript error. Thanks wonkim00

Answer (score 0):

The controlId should be the id of the button to generate async postback else full postback occurs in the page.
For that you can use the clientidmode as static e.g

```
<asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server"  ClientIDMode="Static"/>

   //then you can use below code
   _doPostBack('button1', '');//clientidmode forces buttonid = id given by us
```

Check its correct?

If so then you can get the async postback instead of a  full page postback.

This helped me.
Thanks @Tim for his comment.