# doPostBack doesn't firing

Tags: c#, javascript, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, dopostback

I'm following this post: http://www.thorntontechnical.com/tech/sharepoint/sharepoint-2010-document-sets-custom-ribbon-buttons-with-custom-code/comment-page-1#comment-35294 to get a event in a ribbon button.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction 
Id="Hello_world"
RegistrationType="List"
RegistrationId="101"
Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
Sequence="5">
<CommandUIExtension>
  <CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Documents.Manage.Controls._children">
      <Button 
        Id="Ribbon.ManageDocumentSet.MDS.Manage.Controls.CustomButton" 
        TemplateAlias="o1" 
        ToolTipDescription="Demonstrate a ribbon doing something cool"
        ToolTipTitle="Download as Zip" 
        LabelText="Weeeee"
        Alt="Weee" 
        Command="Ribbon.ManageDocumentSet.MDS.Manage.CustomButtonClick" 
        Sequence="20"/>
    </CommandUIDefinition>
  </CommandUIDefinitions>
  <CommandUIHandlers>
         <CommandUIHandler Command="Ribbon.ManageDocumentSet.MDS.Manage.CustomButtonClick" CommandAction="javascript:__doPostBack('MyDelegateEvent', '');"/>
  </CommandUIHandlers>
     </CommandUIExtension>
   </CustomAction>
 </Elements>
```

This xml put the ribbon in the Documents.Manage tab.

```
 <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
   <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
   <Control
     ControlClass="SharePointProject1.MyClass"
     ControlAssembly="SharePointProject1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,      PublicKeyToken=f5b43d1a96c6223e"
Sequence="50" Id="AdditionalPageHead"/>
 </Elements><Control
     ControlClass="SharePointProject1.MyClass"
ControlAssembly="SharePointProject1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f5b43d1a96c6223e"
     Sequence="50" Id="AdditionalPageHead"/>
 </Elements>
```

Control class xml...

And finally cs class:

```
 namespace SharePointProject1
{
    public class MyClass : WebControl
    {
        const string MYEVENT = "MyDelegateEvent";

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            this.EnsureChildControls();
            base.OnLoad(e);
            if (this.Page.Request["__EVENTTARGET"] == MYEVENT)
            {
                // custom code here
                int itemId = Convert.ToInt32(this.Page.Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"]);
                System.IO.TextWriter mywriterFired = new StreamWriter(@"C:\zzz_CodeBehindFileItemMenu.txt", true);
                mywriterFired.WriteLine("Event Fired at:" + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + ": Item ID:" + itemId.ToString());
                mywriterFired.Close();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I added in assembly this code.... But the __doPostBack event never firing.....
Does everyone know what could be the reason??

Comment: The code seems to be OK, Try changing OnLoad to OnInit.
Example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874461/prevent-full-postback-from-dopostback

Comment: It doesn't work Mariano. Thanks for your reply